# каким членом является инфинитив?

Tags: лексика

Учитесь выразительно читать вслух.Желание говорить правду похвально.Все стали весело смеяться.Пойдем на реку купаться.Напишите ,чем является инфинитив?

Comment: Марина, но у Вас самой-то хоть какие-нибудь мысли по этому вопросу есть?

Comment: оно не будет тут сказуемым!!ТУт оно может быть дополнением,определением или существительным.

Comment: Ну, существительное - вообще не член. Оно - часть.  Посмотрите на сказуемые ещё разок, их там три вида разных...

Comment: Подсказка: в одном из приведённых Вами предложений инфинитив является **определением**, в другом -- **дополнением**, в третьем -- **обстоятельством**, в четвёртом -- частью **составного глагольного сказуемого**.  Постарайтесь найти сами эти предложения.

Comment: Простите, Вы, Слава, или кто-то ещё можете дать ссылочку, где можно почитать про члены предложения с такими подробностями, чтобы понимать всё, о чём тут говорят? Спасибо заранее!

Comment: http://philolog.pspu.ru/module/magazine/do/mpub_15_303

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила!

Answer (score 1):

Учитесь выразительно читать вслух (дополнение).

Желание говорить правду похвально (несогласованное определение).

Все стали весело смеяться (составное глагольное сказуемое).

Пойдем на реку купаться (обстоятельство цели).

Примечание

Обычно инфинитив является дополнением, если действия глаголов относятся к разным лицам (субъект и объект): Он приказал стрелять.  Значительно реже встречаются случаи, когда инфинитив-дополнение обозначает действие того же субъекта: Вчера мы договорились (о чем?) поехать на дачу. За неделю он научился (чему?) кататься на коньках.

Answer (score 0):

1-ое предложение - часть глагольного сказуемого или дополнение (можно задать вопрос что делать? или чему? (Бывают конструкции типа: учиться (чему?) счёту))
2-ое предложение - дополнение (вопрос чего? (Бывают конструкции типа: желание (чего?) зла))
3-е предложение - часть глагольного сказуемого (вопрос что делать?)
4-ое предложение - часть глагольного сказуемого или обстоятельство цели (вопрос что делать? или зачем?)